# Call to a member function searchActivityByName() on null

Tags: php, frameworks, codeigniter-2

I am just working on my websites APIs, and when i tested it on localhost it seems to be working fine as it should be but  when i uploaded it on the live server it gave me

> error : Call to a member function `searchActivityByName()` on null.

My code is in the helper is :

```
function searchActivityByTitle($Actname,$persons=false,$price_filter=false,$time_filter=false,$limit = false, $offset = false) {

        $ci =& get_instance();
    //$Actname = !empty($Actname)?$Actname:"kite";
        $data = $ci->ActivitiesModel->searchActivityByName($Actname, true, $persons, $price_filter, $time_filter,$limit, $offset);

        if(!empty($data)) 
            return array("data"=>$data["data"], "total_results" => $data["count"]);
        else
            return false;
    }
```

Any help or suggestions would be appertiated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

That usually happens in CI if the function can't be found because (1) the model/helper/library isn't loaded (2) the model/helper/library isn't loaded  because it isn't named right.

Try loading the model in the function if it isn't already loaded/autoloaded before calling the helper function. Otherwise make sure the model is named correctly  and defined correctly according to CI standards (on linux systems e.g. "live server" 
 this is usually the issue).

Standards:

model file: models/some_model.php

definition: `class Some_model { }`

load: `$this->load->model('some_model'); $this->some_model->some_method();`